# UIModalPresentationFormSheet covers full screen?

Tags: ios, ipad, fullscreen, cover

I did not get the solution for this:

```
 miRevealController *reveal = [[self navigationController] revealController];
    [reveal showViewController:[reveal frontViewController]];
    reveal.frontViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [reveal.frontViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What is/was the question here?